# El apartado "if" por muchos que ponga para encadenar, no me los detecta

Tags: python

Al seguir viendo el video donde estoy aprendiendo Python relacionado con el Condicional IF. Los **if** siguen sin funcionar. Expongo el código:

```
import random

print("Bienvenido/a, adivina un numero de entre el 0 y el 10")

numero_ganador = random.randint(0, 10) #Esto para hacer random el numero
numero_azar = int(input("¿Cual crees que es el número de la suerte?"))


if numero_azar == numero_ganador:
    print("Felicidades, lo has acetado")

if numero_ganador > 10:
    print("Te has pasado un poco, es entre 0 y 10")

else:
    print("Este era el numero a adivinar {} ".format(numero_ganador))
```

Bien, a partir del apartado `if numero_ganador > 10: print("Te has pasado un poco, es entre 0 y 10")`
No me lo detecta y en la consola al poner un numero mayor a 10 no me pone el `print`. El primer IF y el ELSE si lo detectan y tengo mi resultado, pero lo que haya entre medio no me lo lee en la consola

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Te has liado con los nombres de las variables. Lo correcto es:

```
numero_azar = random.randint(0, 10) #Esto para hacer random el numero
numero_ganador = int(input("¿Cual crees que es el número de la suerte?"))
```

También en el último `print`.

El código con los nombres corregidos es:

```
import random

print("Bienvenido/a, adivina un numero de entre el 0 y el 10")

numero_azar = random.randint(0, 10) #Esto para hacer random el numero
numero_ganador = int(input("¿Cual crees que es el número de la suerte?"))

if numero_azar == numero_ganador:
    print("Felicidades, lo has acetado")

if numero_ganador > 10:
    print("Te has pasado un poco, es entre 0 y 10")
else:
    print("Este era el numero a adivinar {} ".format(numero_azar))
```

Comment: Exactamente ese es el error, ¿no sería también más útil utilizar un ELIF en vez del segundo IF?

Comment: @arielberinstein. Correcto, pero quise mantener las modificaciones al mínimo.

Comment: Esta bien. Así puede tenerlo en cuenta @Sundente.

Answer (score 0):

## otra forma de dar solucion, se modifico un poco

import random

print("Bienvenido/a, adivina un numero de entre el 0 y el 10")

numero_ganador = random.randint(0, 10) #Esto para hacer random el numero
numero_azar = int(input("¿Cual crees que es el número de la suerte?"))

if numero_azar == numero_ganador:
print("Felicidades, lo has acetado")

elif numero_azar > numero_ganador:
print("Te has pasado un poco, es entre 0 y 10")

else:
print(f"Este era el numero a adivinar {format(numero_ganador)} ")**texto en negrita**

Comment: ¿Y cuál fue la modificación? Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.